# How do I get the associations between Test Cases and Test Suites/Test Plans in an SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

### An outline of the problem:

In Microsoft Test Manager, we have lost some Test Results along the way, because testing was done in Test Manager with the wrong starting configurations. On correcting the configurations in the Test Plan, the Test Results have become dis-associated with the plan because their configurations do not match the new configurations in the Test Plan.

I now want to report on the testing that came before the configuration changes, because the test results are still valuable. Unfortunately these do not appear in the OLAP cube that reports on the results (because of the dis-association) but they are still present in the relational database. See this link, on the subject of querying the [TFS_Warehouse] database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620635.aspx

So the first part of the problem is resurrection of the test results. This is accomplished by querying the test results by using the FactTestResult table and the associated dimension tables.

Secondly, I have to show these results in the context of the Test Plan. In other words I can't just provide a Test Case Id and say whether it passed or failed. It needs to be show in which Test Suite it resides. And this is where the problem begins...

Looking at the information in the msdn link above, you would think that it is just a case of using the TestSuiteSK field from the FactTestResult table, but NO: In many cases this field is NULL.

### Things I've tried:

So I have tried joining the FactTestResult back onto the FactTestResult to fill in the blank TestSuiteSK from other records.
This works up to a point but it is not perfect.

### What I'd like to try:

It seems like it would be much simpler to start with the TestSuite and join the Test Cases and then join the Test Results.
So the question is this:

Which database holds the links between the Test Case Work Items and the Test Suites. As described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159334.aspx#sec14

I have searched the [TFS_Warehouse] database extensively, but this information is definitely not held in there.

Comment: It's not recommended to work in database directly, you can use TFS API to get all Test Suites hierarchy Test Cases, you can check blog: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/07/06/tfs-api-part-27-test-plans-test-suites-test-cases-mapping/

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but as no-one else has answered, I've used the API to export all the test cases and test suites and then joined the test results using an SQL query to the test suite details. Thanks for your help.